# Custom langchain tool not completing agent pipeline

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I'm trying to make a AI assistant capable of sending messages on discord

I'm having trouble understanding why the discord function doesn't validate the agent pipeline in this code :

```
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.agents import Tool, initialize_agent, AgentType
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory

load_dotenv()

def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return (fib(n-1) + fib(n-2))

def discord(message):
    prompt = PromptTemplate(
        template="""
            You are a message interpreter for Discord messages, extract the recipient and the core of the message in this message : {message}.
            Output MUST be a JSON FORMAT: 
            "recipient": recipient,
            "message": message,
        """, 
        input_variables=["message"],
    )

    llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)

    chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt, verbose=True)

    response = chain.run(message)
    jsonResp = json.loads(response)
    return f"Successfully sent {jsonResp['message']} to {jsonResp['recipient']} "


tools = [
    Tool(
        name="Fibonacci",
        func=lambda n: str(fib(int(n))),
        description="Use when you want to calculate the nth fibonnaci number"
    ),
    Tool(
        name="Discord",
        func=lambda str: discord(str),
        description="Use when you want to send a message using Discord"
    ),
]


memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)
llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, verbose=True)


agent_chain = initialize_agent(
    tools,
    llm,
    agent=AgentType.CHAT_CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
    memory=memory,
    verbose=True
)

response = agent_chain.run(input="Ask John on discord to grab some apple before coming home ")

print(f"response : {response}")
```

How can I make my discord function validate the agent pipeline ? I don't understand why it doesn't accept the string "Successfully sent Can you grab some apples on your way home? to John" as a tool response.

Here are the logs when calling the script :

```
Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
{
    "action": "Discord",
    "action_input": "Hey John, can you grab some apples on your way home?"
}

> Entering new LLMChain chain...
Prompt after formatting:

            You are a message interpreter for Discord messages, extract the recipient and the core of the message 
in this message : Hey John, can you grab some apples on your way home?.
            Output MUST be a JSON FORMAT:
            "recipient": recipient,
            "message": message,


> Finished chain.
Successfully sent Can you grab some apples on your way home? to John {
    "action": "Final Answer",
    "action_input": "There was no tool response. Your last comment was 'Okay, so what is the response to my last comment?'"
}

> Finished chain.
response : There was no tool response. Your last comment was 'Okay, so what is the response to my last comment?'
```

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem lies in the output format of the `discord` function. Convert the output to a string in JSON format using `json.dumps`. This ensures the output of the Discord function matches the format expected by the agent.

Answer (score 0):

Add one line in your description: answer based on observation, see below

```html
description="Use when you want to send a message using Discord.\
        Answer based on the observation."
```

[image]